# Proofs in appendix referencing theorem but without restating theorem

Tags: miktex

New to MikTex/LaTex, so bear with me.

I went through the questions here related to proofs in appendix but couldn't find exactly what I am looking for, which is:

I'd like to have all proofs of theorems, lemmas, etc, in one appendix. Instead of restating the theorem I would like to have each proof in the appendix start for instance as follows: *Proof of Lemma XX*.

What would be the most straighforward way to achieve this?

Comment: You could use the `thmtools` package  to define an new theoremstyle with the `headformat=...` key.

Comment: Using the `amsthm` package and its `proof` env one just uses `\begin{proof}[Proof of Lemma~\ref{lem:xxx}]`. I often make a wrapper env called `proofof` which takes `Lemma~\ref{lem:xxx}` as a mandatory arg and automatically fills in the rest

Comment: @daleif thank you, yes I think that is the easiest way to do it. I couldn't find anything in the packages proof-at-the-end or apxproof that could do this easier.